# Insert streamed XML data database

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, mongodb

I am trying to efficiently insert a lot of data (XML file is over 70GB in size) without crashing my MongoDB server. Currently this is what I am doing using [`xml-stream`](https://github.com/assistunion/xml-stream) in NodeJS:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    XmlStream = require('xml-stream'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    assert = require('assert'),
    ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
    url = 'mongodb://username:password@my.server:27017/mydatabase',
    amount = 0;

var stream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'motor.xml'));
var xml = new XmlStream(stream);

xml.collect('ns:Statistik');
xml.on('endElement: ns:Statistik', function(item) {
    var insertDocument = function(db, callback) {
        db.collection('vehicles').insertOne(item, function(err, result) {
            amount++;
            if (amount % 1000 == 0) {
                console.log("Inserted", amount);
            }
            callback();
        });
    };

    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        insertDocument(db, function() {
            db.close();
        });
    });
});
```

When I call the `xml.on()` it basically returns the tree/element I am currently on. Since this is straight up JSON, I can just give it to my `db.collection().insertOne()` function as a parameter and it will insert it into the database exactly how I want it.

All of the code actually works as it is now, but it stops after about 3000 insertions (which takes about 10 seconds). I suspect it's because I open a database connection, insert the data, and then close the connection each and every time I see a tree in the XML file, in this case about 3000 times.

I could, somehow, incorporate the `insertMany()` function and do it in chunks of 100s (or more), but I'm not quite sure how that would work with it all being streamed and asynchronous.

So my question is: How do I insert a large amount of XML (to JSON) into my MongoDB database without it crashing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right to presume [`.insertMany()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#insertMany) would be better than writing every single time, so it's really just a matter of collecting the data on the ["stream"](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html).

Since the execution is "async", you typically want to avoid having too many active calls on the stack, so usually you [`.pause()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause) the ["stream"](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) before calling the [`.insertMany()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#insertMany) and then [`.resume()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_resume) once the callback is complete:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    XmlStream = require('xml-stream'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    url = 'mongodb://username:password@my.server:27017/mydatabase',
    amount = 0;

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

    var stream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'motor.xml'));
    var xml = new XmlStream(stream);

    var docs = [];
    //xml.collect('ns:Statistik');

    // This is your event for the element matches
    xml.on('endElement: ns:Statistik', function(item) {
        docs.push(item);           // collect to array for insertMany
        amount++;

        if ( amount % 1000 === 0 ) { 
          xml.pause();             // pause the stream events
          db.collection('vehicles').insertMany(docs, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            docs = [];             // clear the array
            xml.resume();          // resume the stream events
          });
        }
    });

    // End stream handler - insert remaining and close connection
    xml.on("end",function() {
      if ( amount % 1000 !== 0 ) {
        db.collection('vehicles').insertMany(docs, function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          db.close();
        });
      } else {
        db.close();
      }
    });

});
```

Or even modernizing it somewhat:

```
const fs = require('fs'),
      path = require('path'),
      XmlStream = require('xml-stream'),
      MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const uri = 'mongodb://username:password@my.server:27017/mydatabase';

(async function() {

  let amount = 0,
      docs = [],
      db;

  try {

    db = await MongoClient.connect(uri);

    const stream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'motor.xml')),
          xml = new XmlStream(stream);

    await Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      xml.on('endElement: ns:Statistik', async (item) => {
        docs.push(item);
        amount++;

        if ( amount % 1000 === 0 ) {
          try {
            xml.pause();
            await db.collection('vehicle').insertMany(docs);
            docs = [];
            xml.resume();
          } catch(e) {
            reject(e)
          }
        }

      });

      xml.on('end',resolve);

      xml.on('error',reject);
    });

    if ( amount % 1000 !== 0 ) {
      await db.collection('vehicle').insertMany(docs);
    }

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    db.close();
  }

})();
```

Note that the `MongoClient` connection actually wraps all the other operations. You only want to connect **once**, and the other operations happen on the event handlers for the ["stream"](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html).

So for your `XMLStream` the event handler is triggered on the expression match and the data extracted and collected to an array. Every 1000 items the [`.insertMany()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#insertMany) call is made to insert the documents, "pausing" and "resuming" over the "async" call.

Once complete the "end" event is fired on the ["stream"](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html). This is where you close the database connection, and the event loop will be released and end the program.

Whilst it's possible to get some degree  of "parallelism" by allowing various [`.insertMany()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#insertMany) calls to occur at once ( and typically to a "pooled size" so as to not overrun the call stack ), this is basically how the process looks in the simplest form by simply pausing whilst waiting for the other async I/O to complete.

> **NOTE**: Commenting out the `.collect()` method from your original code as per the [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45527488/2313887) this would appear not to be necessary and in fact is retaining the nodes in memory that really should be discarded after each write to the database.

Comment: Oh boy, it looks like it works! I was trying to pull off my own basically doing what you do, but I couldn't wrap my head around having an open connection. My problem was, it gave me very inconsistent results. If I inserted 1000 records, it would only actually show 300 in the database (around that). Probably because I simply close the connection at random times before it's done. Thanks a lot, Neil!

Comment: On another note: Do you have any clue why it starts to go REALLY! slow after about 75000 inserts? We're talking about 1000/sec when the database is empty, but maybe 100-200/sec when I hit around 75000.

Comment: @MortenMoulder You should see a marked improvement using `.insertMany()`, but as to general differences in throughput depending on how much data is there, well that's an entirely different and really broad subject. There are too many factors to consider without specifics, such as what indexes are in place ( if any ), available memory, distribution of writes and basic hardware. If you have other questions it's usually best to  [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) where you can clearly express the details.

Comment: That's alright. I've seen a big improvement in precision, none the less. I get a "JavaScript heap out of memory" from the garbage collector right now, which could hint at what's wrong haha. Thanks!

Comment: @MortenMoulder From the above code? Because what I'm telling you to do in the listing is to `.pause()` and `.resume()` the stream over async calls. So if you are seeing anything such out of the listing above, then the only possible area is the xml-stream is actually leaking somewhere. A quick browse to the repo suggests it's just a light wrapper over Expat, so I find that unlikely.

Comment: Well something is definitely leaking, because my memory usage increases to about 95% and the operation is slow as hell. See my [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45527488/javascript-heap-out-of-memory-while-streaming-large-file) if you're interested.