# "JavaScript heap out of memory" while streaming large file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, memory

I am trying to XML -> JSON -> MongoDB on my server. I have a NodeJS application which streams the XML, converts it into JSON, then adds it to the MongoDB server in chunks of 1000s. However, after about 75000 records, my Macbook's fans starts spinning faster and the processing goes REALLY slow. After a few minutes, I get this error:

> <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> [30517:0x102801600]   698057 ms: Mark-sweep 1408.2 (1702.9) -> 1408.1 (1667.4) MB, 800.3 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 0 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 803 ms) last resort 
>   [30517:0x102801600]   698940 ms: Mark-sweep 1408.1 (1667.4) -> 1408.1 (1667.4) MB, 882.2 / 0.0 ms  last resort

and finally in the JS stacktrace:

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

I have a feeling my memory is running out, but increasing the allowed memory with `--max-old-space-size` (or whatever) doesn't work when the file is 70+ gigabytes and I only have 16GB of RAM.

Here's the code of what I am trying to do:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    XmlStream = require('xml-stream'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    url = 'mongodb://username:password@my.server:27017/mydatabase',
    amount = 0;

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

    var stream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'motor.xml'));
    var xml = new XmlStream(stream);

    var docs = [];
    xml.collect('ns:Statistik');

    // This is your event for the element matches
    xml.on('endElement: ns:Statistik', function(item) {
        docs.push(item);           // collect to array for insertMany
        amount++;

        if ( amount % 1000 === 0 ) { 
          xml.pause();             // pause the stream events
          db.collection('vehicles').insertMany(docs, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            docs = [];             // clear the array
            xml.resume();          // resume the stream events
          });
        }
    });

    // End stream handler - insert remaining and close connection
    xml.on("end",function() {
      if ( amount % 1000 !== 0 ) {
        db.collection('vehicles').insertMany(docs, function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          db.close();
        });
      } else {
        db.close();
      }
    });

});
```

My question is something like: Do I have a memory leak? Why does Node allow the code to build up the memory like that? Is there a fix besides buying 70+ GB of RAM for my PC?

Comment: _"when the file is 70+ gigabytes and I only have 16GB of RAM."_ What is expected result? What is the purpose of a single 70GB file, that is not an entire OS build?

Comment: @guest271314 My theory is, the data I add to the external MongoDB gets stored in memory on my machine, as it never clears it (except when I do `docs = []`).

Comment: Not familiar enough with node.js or mongodb to provide a verifiable evaluation. The 70GB file is interesting at first glance. Or is the 70GB total data transfer mentioned at Question one or more directories which contain files?

Comment: @guest271314 70 gigabyte in one XML file. It contains a lot of data, haha.

Comment: You can try using `ReadableStream` and possibly `.pipeTo()` and `WritableStream`  to stream the data from one location to another. Though have not tried to stream that amount of data previously. Have been able to request a stream of and download a 189MB file [How to solve Uncaught RangeError when download large size json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39959467/), the same principles should apply, given adequate RAM and disk space, possibly with garbage collection occurring at each read.

Comment: It's quite possible that `1000` is actually too big a batch size to store the contents in an array, but unlikely since the BSON Limit is 16MB and `insertMany()` would simply fail if the array content supplied exceeded that size. If there is anything "leaking" it would have to be in the XML stream itself.

Comment: `except when I do docs = []` so what's wrong with doing just that?

Comment: @NeilLunn Changing it to 500 or even 100 wouldn't make a difference, would it? If it builds up over time anyway, storing 1000 or 100 in an array doesn't really matter much.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Nothing, simply saying there's no way of saying "clear this from memory as well". Poorly worded by me I guess.

Comment: @guest271314 I've successfully handled many gigabyte files before by using web workers. However, it's a whole different thing when it comes to streaming, as you can't just start off somewhere except the start.

Comment: What am I telling you is that it **would likely not make any difference** due to the BSON Limit. A "stream" is **meant** to be only processing each item as it is matched. This actually "pauses" and "resumes" over each async call and therefore there **should** only be the active batch collection and no other items being processed. But if there is a fault in the XML stream, then it would not be releasing memory from previously parsed items. Nothing to do with the database or operations with.

Comment: @MortenMoulder Yes, though you can control the stream. That is, you can await certainty that adequate memory is freed before calling next read. All of the fragments do not need to be read at once. Not sure why you are expecting to read 70GB at a machine that does not support that capability. When first tried approach at linked Question was at a machine that had perhaps 500MB or less of available disk space. The result was it took 4 minutes and 20 seconds to complete the task. At a different machine the result not distinguishable from downloading a file of substantially less content size.

Comment: @NeilLunn Right okay, gotcha. I'm trying with a smaller chunk size as we speak. Let's see if that makes any difference (it shouldn't).

Comment: It's funny... As soon as I start NodeJS and it starts processing, I can see it starting from < 100 MB RAM and slowly ramp up to a lot more. Clearly something isn't right.

Comment: Try removing the code that writes to MongoDB and just see if it's a problem with `xml-stream` and the way you're reading the file. At least you will know where to look to optimise.

Comment: Also, post the document structure.

Comment: I am not familiar with mongodb in particular, but many dbs have an explicit flush to disk. Otherwise, I am assuming the `item`s in `docs` contain the large portions of data. My guess then is that something is holding a reference to the data contained in `docs`, probably a copy of the reference. You could test that by nulling the array before losing reference to it yourself, aka `docs.forEach((_, i) => { docs[i] = null; });`. If that doesn't help either something is even copying the references from the array elements or it's something completely different and i don't know.

Comment: @Strelok I've come down to it's xml-stream. I did comment out the MongoDB insertions, but it still starts throttling and crashes before 100k records. What a bummer.

Comment: I think it's your usage of `.collect` I think it's only needed to collect sub items and you probably don't need to cal it as I can see by the name you're already processing ea h element anyway. Hard to say without seeing your structure. What's happening is even as you're streaming them,`collect` forces them to be saved in memory.

Comment: Just looked through the xml-stream docs and examples and the usage of `collect` does appear to be incorrect here. It would seem that your actual event processing should be `xml.on("updateElement: ns:Statistik", ...` or possibly just `endElement` and not to use `collect` at all. It's intended purpose is to "collect child nodes", and what you want is to instead gather all data for a particular node match. See https://github.com/assistunion/xml-stream/blob/master/examples/http-stream.js. My guess would be that "collect" is "holding on to" items that you really want to discard.

Comment: @NeilLunn Shit, yep, you're completely right. Commenting out the `xml.collect('ns:Statistik')` line results in a steady 100 MB RAM usage. Woohoo, success! Thanks a lot, man.

Comment: Give the credit to @Strelok. I just looked at the docs and came to the conclusion, and when I looked here they had just posted the same conclusion. I just added to point out the usage example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer, since it solved the issue and might be useful to others having difficulting using the `xml-stream` package in this way.

In question, the `collect` method is causing the issue as it is forcing the parser to collect all the instances of the processed node in an array as they are parsed. `collect` should only be used to collect children items of a certain type from each node that is being parsed. The default behaviour is not to do that (due to the streaming nature of the parser that lets you process multi gigabyte files with ease).

So solution was to remove that line of code and just use the `endElement` event.

Comment: 2022 and this really helped me solve the same heap memory issue with node. To clarify: I understood the xml-stream API as follows:

1: You schedule `.on('endElement:...` events
2: Then you start collecting with `.collect(...)`

Turns out that simply binding the `endElement` event is enough to trigger the xml collecting/parsing, which - to me - was counter-intuitive.